# Checkbox issue in ListView Scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview with text and checkbox. The checkbox are behaving weirdly while scrolling the list view. It seems to be a recycling issue. Anyways I tried various options suggested in some similar posts but none of them working for me. I tried set and get tag position as suggested in one of the posts but hard luck. I am using custom adapter in my activity file for the list view. Below are some code snippets;
 Activity class:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemdisplay_listview);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, itemNames, tableNo));
```

Custom Adapter:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<String> mListItems;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        ViewHolder holder;
        int a = 1;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayList,
                String table) {
            tableNumber = table;
            mListItems = arrayList;

            // get the layout inflater
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mListItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {

            TextView itemName, quantity;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            ImageButton addBtn, minusBtn;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            // create a ViewHolder reference

            // check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null
            // then
            // reuse it
            if (convertview == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertview = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.itemdisplay_list, null);

                holder.itemName = (TextView) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_name);
                holder.addBtn = (ImageButton) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_add);
                holder.minusBtn = (ImageButton) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_minus);
                holder.quantity = (TextView) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_quantity);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_cbox);

                // holder.checkbox.setTag(position);


                // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
                convertview.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the
                // view
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
            }

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(checkListener);
            doneBtn.setEnabled(true);

            holder.minusBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
            holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(a));
            holder.addBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
            holder.addBtn.setOnClickListener(addBtnClick);
            holder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(minusBtnClick);

            String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);

            if (stringItem != null) {
                if (holder.itemName != null) {
                    // set the item name on the TextView
                    holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
                }
            }

            // this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the
            // specified position.
            return convertview;

        }

        private OnClickListener checkListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*doneBtn.setOnClickListener(doneBtnClick);*/
                View view = (View) v.getParent();

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_cbox);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_name);
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemdisplaylist_quantity);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    map.put(tv.getText().toString(), tv1.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map
                            .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

                        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
                        String item = entry.getKey();
                        if ((tv.getText().toString()).equals(item)) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        };
```

I have been struggling for quite a long time. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: check it out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have say data for **100  CBs**, then you also need to store their `checked/unchecked state`. lets say a boolean array of 100 elements **CheckedStatus[100]**. in GetView do

```
 if(CheckedStatus[position] == true) {
 // check the check box
 } else {
 // uncheck it 
}.
```

The position is the one received in the GetView function

Answer (score 1):

in the custom listview adapter call **setChecked** ***after*** calling **setOnCheckedChangeListener**.This way you sever the link to the old listener from the recycled view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `boolean checked` variable to `ViewHolder`. Change it in `checkListener`. Then in `getView` add `holder.checkbox.setChecked(holder.checked)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as suggested but still same issue. Trying other options now.

Comment: Just make a new arrayList which contains your checked checkbox position. pass it to your adapter and in adapter modify the arraylist and user holder.checkbox.setOncheckChangeListener(){}. inside this write your logic to modify the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to have some sort of model object which retains the state of your checkbox, then use that model instead of a simple String as your datastructure:

```
// Oversimplified, but adiquate for our purposes.
public class ItemModel
{
    public String text;
    public boolean isChecked;
}
```

Then, instead of passing an array of Strings to the adapter, pass an array of `ItemModels`.
The string you'll need will be the text parameter, and then you must set the checkbox value to the `isChecked` value.

All that's left is changing the `isChecked` value once the state of the checkbox changes.
Do this inside the getItem method, inside the `if(convertView == null)` block, after you've initialized the `holder.checkbox` parameter. Also, make sure to make the `position` variable in the method parameters `final`.

Here's the code:

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                mListItems.get(position).isChecked = isChecked;

            }
        });
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are getting bitten by the recycle issue.
I suggest that you remove the listener first using the following in the else statement

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

In your code as follows:

```
} else {
                // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the
                // view
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
                holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried as suggested but still same issue.